# Does jQuery ajax method actually "return" if it's in the complete function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I did figure out my issue, but I thought that in the ajax function, when the `complete` function runs, and you have a `return VARIABLE` inside, it should return that value.

Example:

**Wrong**

```
var result = doStuff();
console.log('return from function doStuff(): ---' + result);

function doStuff() {
    $.ajax({
        ....
        ....
        complete: function (data) {
            // this will return true or false, boolean
            // in my instance, I'm returning false from the api controller
            var testing = $.parseJSON(data.responseText);
            console.log('return from api controller: ---' + testing );
            return testing;
        },
        error: function (response) {
            console.log(response.responseText);
        }
    });

    return true;  // this is obviously being returned, not the one above
}
```

I would think that **both** `console.log` would have **false** for the values of the variables. Since the `complete` function has the return, it'll never hit the bottom return.

[image]

Obviously that's not the case. Why not?

---

Instead, if I declare the variable, `var testing = true;`, then set the value again in the `complete` function, and return that, it works correctly. But that still doesn't answer why the above scenario doesn't work (or do what I would think) correctly.

**Right**

```
var result = doStuff();
console.log('return from function doStuff(): ---' + result);

function doStuff() {
    var testing = true;
    $.ajax({
        ....
        ....
        complete: function (data) {
            // this will return true or false, boolean
            // in my instance, I'm returning false from the api controller
            testing = $.parseJSON(data.responseText);
            console.log('return from api controller: ---' + testing );

            // removed the "return" since the bottom is being hit
        },
        error: function (response) {
            console.log(response.responseText);
        }
    });

    return testing;
}
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**:

Just to clarify, my ajax function is using `async: false`

```
$.ajax({
     ....
     async: false,
     ... other stuff
});
```

Comment: You can't `return` from an AJAX call. You need to use callbacks.

Comment: even if `async` is false?

Comment: @RobScott Yes, even if it is sync. however, if it's sync, your second option would work. (it's still not a good idea)

Comment: Look at it this way. $.ajax accepts an object with properties, and one of those properties in your case contains a callback. If $.ajax ignored the return value from the callback (which it does), then returning from the callback will accomplish nothing because that returned value will not be stored anywhere or passed back out to the parent context.

Comment: ok i didn't know that. i'll read up along w/ the promises, etc. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *does* return the value; it has to, that's just how JS works.

Where you're confused is that it's not *your* code calling the `complete` function, so *you* don't get the return–the code that's calling it does (jQuery in this case).

Your second example *relies* on a synchronous Ajax call (making it a Jax call), and the code should reflect you're making a synchronous call, otherwise it will fail to operate the way you expect (and confuse question readers).

Comment: so there's no way to do it in the first snippet? it has to be the way I did it in the 2nd one?

Comment: @RobScott The whole point of async calls is the async part. You could pass a callback into `doStuff` that handles the completion success; personally I prefer promises, e.g., `when`/etc.

Comment: Note: It's still AJAX even if it's not asynchronous. If you use different acronyms for all kinds of asynchronous/synchronous calls, you end up with AJAX, JAX, AJAJ, JAJ, AJAT, JAT, AJAH, JAH, and more for any format of return data that you can think of...